# Handling more than 2 Fact Tables in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview, fact

I am new to Qlikview and I am trying to get a solution to Link more than 3 Fact Table, I've used the approach on "Handling Multiple fact tables in Qlikview", and works perfectly, however when I am trying to link a 3rd table I get an error of table not found. I have 3 fact tables:

1. Historical Data
2. Sales
3. Credit Memos

All of them share must of the fields:

```
"Document No_",
    "Sell-to Customer No_",
    Type,
    "No_",
     Quantity,
    Amount,
    "Bill-to Customer No_",
    "Posting Date"
```

I've follow steps 1 & 2

1. Create a Temp Fact Table: (Load all Fields)
2. Concatenate your keys and remove individual keys:

My doubt is where I add the new concatenation?

This is the example:

Create your Link Table by concatenating your individual keys into a single table:
This works for Fact tables 1 and 2:

```
[Temp_Link_Table]:

LOAD DISTINCT
'DocNum,
'Cusnum,
'SKU,
'Bill2Num,
   Quantity,
    Amount,
   "Posting Date"
 RESIDENT [Temp_Sales_Line] ;

 CONCATENATE ([Temp_Link_Table])

 LOAD DISTINCT

DocNum,
Cusnum,
SKU,
 Quantity,
    Amount,
   "Posting Date"   

RESIDENT [Temp_Hist_Sales];
```

How should I concatenate the 3?

```
CONCATENATE ([Temp_Link_Table])

 LOAD DISTINCT

DocNum,
Cusnum,
SKU,
 Quantity,
    Amount,
   "Posting Date"   

RESIDENT [Temp_Credit_Memo]?????????????????????????????????

/**
 * The final Link Table will contain all of the individual keys one time as well as your concatenated keys
 */

[Link_table]:

 LOAD DISTINCT

   "Posting Date",
  DocNum,
 Cusnum,
 SKU,
 Quantity,
 Amount,



DocNum &'_'&Cusnum  &'_'& SKU  &'_'& Bill2Num  &'_'&  Quantity  &'_'&Amount &'_'&[Posting Date]     AS Sales_Key, 
DocNum &'_'&Cusnum  &'_'& SKU&'_'&  Quantity  &'_'&Amount &'_'&[Posting Date]   AS Hist_Sales_Key,
DocNum &'_'&Cusnum  &'_'& SKU  &'_'& Bill2Num  &'_'&  Quantity  &'_'&Amount  &'_'&"Posting Date"    AS CreditMemo_Key

 RESIDENT [Temp_Link_Table];


 DROP TABLE [Temp_Sales_Line];
 DROP TABLE [Temp_Hist_Sales];
 DROP TABLE [Temp_CM];
DROP TABLE [Temp_Link_Table];
```

Comment: Is [Temp_Credit_Memo] and actual table like [Temp_Sales_Line] or Temp_Hist_Sales]? Or are you just trying to create a new key?

Comment: Hi bdiamante, thank you very much for your response, Temp_Credit_Memo is an actual table. I get the following message: Table not found
[Sales_Line]:

LOAD 

%DocNum &'_'&%Cusnum  &'_'& %SKU  &'_'&  Quantity  &'_'&Amount  &'_'&"Posting Date" AS Sales_Key, [Doc Type] 

RESIDENT [Temp_Sales_Line]                                    What is odd is when the script is executing I've noticed that Temp_CM ran 2 times one linked to CR Memo

Comment: and one to  Sales Invoice Lines.                                     Connected
CustomerMaster << Mexilink Inc$Customer 1,325 lines fetched
ItemMaster << Mexilink Inc$Item 863 lines fetched
Groups << INL4677 25 lines fetched
Temp_Hist_Sales << 2013 J-M 104,118 lines fetched
Temp_CM << Mexilink Inc$Sales Cr_Memo Line 419 lines fetched
Temp_CM << Mexilink Inc$Sales Invoice Line 63,550 lines fetched

Comment: It looks like the error you are getting is based on some part of your script that's not shown here. Specifically if it cannot find your `Sales_Line` table, you should confirm that the section where you load it has no errors.